# Component is not part of any NgModule although i have declared it in the module

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve lazyloading by creating another routing module and imported the lazy loading  components in it but i am still getting the  following  error. Could someone explain me where i went wrong?
[image]

Here is my code
**setup.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

import {SetupRoutingModule} from './setup-routing.module';
import {DevicesComponent} from './devices/devices.component';
import {StoresComponent} from './stores/stores.component';
import {MaterialModule} from '../../shared/material.module';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SetupRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ DevicesComponent, StoresComponent],
})
export class SetupModule { }
```

**App.module.ts**

```
    import {SetupRoutingModule} from './components/setup/setup-routing.module';
        const routes: Routes = [
          {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
          {path: 'setup', loadChildren: 'app/components/setup/setup.module#SetupModule'},
          {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}

        ];

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            NavbarComponent,
            PublishComponent,
            DashboardComponent,

          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            MaterialModule,
            FlexLayoutModule,
            FormsModule,
            SetupRoutingModule,
            ContentRoutingModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
          ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import **`SetupModule`** inside **`app.module.ts`** under imports

```
imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            MaterialModule,
            FlexLayoutModule,
            FormsModule,
            SetupRoutingModule,
            ContentRoutingModule,
            SetupModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
]
```